# Seeking India population by village, town and city for 1981, 1991, 2001 and 2011?

Tags: data, census, population, india, demography

Trying to source population data for every village, town and city in India.  I have been able to extract data for 2001 & 2011 from the **[census site](http://www.censusindia.gov.in/towns/town.aspx)**, but am having a tough time finding a reliable source for data from 1981 and 1991.

Any thoughts as to where this may be found?

Comment: Do you want the totals? or the Village wise breakdown?

Comment: Devdatta - for some reason I never received a notification of your response to my question...my apologies.  While I've found 1991 and 2001 data, I'm still looking for a village wise breakdown for 1981 and 2011.  I'm only seeing tier 1 city population of 2011 on the census site but would love to get my hands on a data set that shows the population of every   village/town/city.  Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The village wise breakup for 2011hasn't been release as of yet. The 1981 data was released only as books and I don't know if those volumes are still available.

Comment: This is what I have begun to suspect.  Thanks for the info.

Comment: Somewhere here: http://censusindia.gov.in/2011-common/maps.html?

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe - a newer question http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/124785/census-layers-for-india appears to be a duplicate of this one. Would you be interested in creating an answer from your comment?  That way perhaps we can edit this Q&A to become canonical under a title of something like "Creating/sourcing Census Layers for India?" that covers all past and future censuses.

Comment: @Bruno: You are unlikely to get the data that you want. Census of India does not deal with boundries. additionally Village boundries are not well defined in the country. What you have are Revenue Village boundries, and those are available from Survey of India. SoI also sells them connected to Census Data, but that is available only for the 2001 census.

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe No problem - it is now re-opened - anything you can do to make the distinctness clearer in their titles and bodies is much appreciated

Comment: I suspect this question may be more on-topic at the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange, especially if it is only seeking tabular rather than spatial data.

Answer (score 2):

As I have said in my comment, you will not get the layers with 2011 census information.

However village layer with 2001 census information are available from Survey of India at a fixed price.

I have also found some data at this link:
https://archive.org/details/IndiaVillageBoundaries

I cannot vouch for its heritage, completeness or accuracy, but what little I have checked, looks ok to me.