# Seeking downloadable Village layers for India with census 2011 information?

Tags: shapefile, data, census, india, demography

Does anyone know where I could download a layer of all villages in India together with their populations (hopefully from the 2011 census)?

Comment: I've made this a duplicate because I think there is a good case for trying to make the original question into a canonical Q&A on Indian census layers for any year that one has been or will be undertaken. CC @ChrisW

Comment: @PolyGeo: I do not think that this question should be closed, because it is not a duplicate of the linked question. In the Indian Census, the boundries are not well defined; And additionally this question is asking about village boundries, while the linked question talks about town, which are very different according to Census nomenclature.